# Rmpf package error

Tags: r, package, arbitrary-precision

I need to do some high precision calculations so I looked up the net and found the Rmpf package. However, it is throwing some very obvious errors. When I enter the following in console

```
10^(15)*(mpfr((5 + 10^(-15)), 200)- mpfr(5, 200))
```

it gives

```
 1 'mpfr' number of precision  200   bits 
[1] 0.88817841970012523233890533447265625
>
```

whereas, it should give 1.
Am I making a mistake here in using the package?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `mpfr((5 + 10^(-15)), 200)`.
Use `mpfr(5,200) + mpfr(10^(-15), 200)` because the `5+10^(-15)` are calculated with R's double precision arithmetic.

Then

```
10^15*(mpfr(5,200)+mpfr(10^(-15),200) - mpfr(5, 200))
```

will give

```
1 'mpfr' number of precision  200   bits 
[1] 1.000000000000000077705399876661079238307185601195015145492562
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it works. However, it probably loses the point of doing precision arithmetic for me. Suppose I need to find a derivative of a sensitive function numerically. I need to find (1/t)*(f(x+t) - f(x)). How will I compute the derivative if I have to use very small t?

Comment: Convert everything to `mpfr` numbers. Also have a look at the R package `numDeriv`. Or consider complex step derivatives. See [this](http://mdolab.engin.umich.edu/content/guide-complex-step-derivative-approximation-0) with a link to the original article.